# How to avoid a deadlock on frequently updated table

Tags: mysql, server

I have a table of users where each user generates a transaction reference number and updates 1 every time to get a next transaction reference number to use.

The table is similar to this:

UserName varchar(50),
counter int

For example a username: John has a counter number 1
 If he picks a reference number his counter number is updated to 2
so that he will use 2 next time for a reference number.

The problem is that because many users use this table. I get many dealocks as a result. Can any one please advise. Thx

Comment: Have a look: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Answer (score 0):

Would advise creating a new table with `AUTO_INCREMENT` for COUNTER column and insert anyone who wants to get a new COUNTER. The `AUTO_INCREMENT` takes care of assigning a new incremented number to the new row, and you can get the latest number assigned to any particular person from a normal `select` query.

Comment: Thx Srihari, but I have like 200 users in the table and each user creates at least 300 reference number per day. Doing as you suggested would create table with big size of data as a result because it means per day I would insert 60000 rows in this new table.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't prevent deadlocks.

Why? Simply because of how your system is designed to work. I'll quote:

> I have a table of users where each user generates a transaction
>   reference number and updates 1 every time **to get a next transaction**
>   reference number to use

Let's suppose you have only 2 users. Each user issues a query at the same time. Now, what happens is that each user operates with a snapshot of data. So, both of them will calculate, for example, that next transaction number will be `2`.

So, the two threads handling connections will compete for a lock and will end up in deadlock. To fix the problem, MySQL kills one thread, letting the other finish. Why do they compete for a lock? They are looking up the same table / counter / whatever it is and in order to get the *correct* information, that information can't be modified freely by anyone or anything. You most likely don't want to get the same transaction number for every person (thread actually) so MySQL places a lock on a table while doing counter increment.

The root of the problem is that you're trying to obtain what the next number of a transaction would be and multiple people (threads actually) end up looking up the same source to obtain that number.

You don't have too many options here, here they are:

- **handle the deadlocks by re-issuing transactions**, once MySQL tells you there's been a deadlock. That's how it's done. Deadlock isn't something you should fear, it's just database's way of telling you that to keep data integrity, it denied a thread to do its job.
- **redesign your system** so you don't rely on what the next transaction number would be. That part is probably more difficult, and we don't know what relies on this functionality, but - this would be your best option. I don't know if it's possible, so I will suggest you think how you could have your system work if you didn't rely on that next transaction number.